# angularjs ng-options with one element in array

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on angularjs app, and I can't find the answer for simple question. I've got an select with ng-options, when array that is set for options has more then one object inside the select is empty on start, but when array has only one element it automatically set it as default value. I need this select to be empty at the begining all the time, is there any solution?

Comment: show the code how u did the above

Answer (score 0):

in angularJS you may separate the variable used to fill in your options values and the model that stores your selected value.

See that example :

```
       //Model used to store selected values        
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="myModel.country">
            //I have a $scope.countries array of country
            <option ng-repeat="country in countries" ng-value="country" required>{{country.name}}</option>

        </select>
```